# codeigniter cant use redirect function after function ends

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have simple php function:

```
function edit($id = NULL){
  $user_id = 25;
  $event = $this->database->GetSingle('events', array('id' => $id, 'userid' => $user_id));
  $this->data['event'] = $event;

  if($this->form_validation->run('event/createedit') == FALSE){
    $this->ajaxValidation('event/createedit');
  }else{
    if($event == NULL){
      $this->database->Insert('events', $data);
      $event_id = $this -> database -> GetLastID();


    }else{
      $this->database->Update('events', $data, array('id' => $event['id']));
      $event_id = $event['id'];
    }
    redirect('user/event/show/'.$event_id);
  }
}
```

and no matter what CI function of redirect I use, it's not working.. 
but in chrome development tools > network tab i see that it tries to load what page, but then comes another action what is same.

The address is good, function `show($id = null)` also is good
maybe someone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Ajax call to this function. If using ajax the redirect function doesn't work.

Comment: i was using simple <input type="submit"> button for that action.. :) 
well i made work around.. made ajax call function for submiting my that form.. and when i get event_id returned in function i use javascript location.href function to change page.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect statement in Codeigniter sends the user to the specified web page using a redirect header statement.

This statement resides in the URL helper which is loaded in the following way:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

The redirect function loads a local URI specified in the first parameter of the function call and built using the options specified in your config file.

The second parameter allows the developer to use different HTTP commands to perform the redirect "location" or "refresh".

According to the CodeIgniter documentation: "Location is faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem."

Example:

```
if ($user_logged_in === FALSE) {

     redirect('/account/login', 'refresh');

}
```

Comment: i have url helper already in my autoload.. the redirect() function is working if i put it before `if($this->form_validation->run('event/createedit') == FALSE)` statement

and none of it refresh or location not helping.. just tried.